# Default permalink structure with pagination on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, permalinks

My goal is to set my pagination permalink structure from /page/#/ to ?page=#, while using /%postname%/ as my permalink structure. I have changed the link structure with the get_pagenum_link filter, but it still redirects me to the standard /page/#/ instead of the ?page=# I want.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. I added a filter to redirect_canonical and returned false. I don't know much about that so hopefully that doesn't cause problems down the road on my site.